# Xlwings + Pygatt: Storing object from Pygatt into Excel VBA

Tags: user-defined-functions, xlwings

I am able to send-receive data between VBA code and Python UDF using xlwings.

I am using Pygatt in the Python UDF to communicate with BLE devices.

I am storing information in one of the sheets in Excel and accessing it in Python UDF as required.

My problem is, i am unable to store the value of *adapter* and use in another UDF:-

```
adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend(serial_port=str(comPort))
adapter.start()
```

My idea is store the adapter value in one of the cells in Excel sheet, then access it in another UDF.

Following are my UDFs:-

```
#Function to open BLE connection based on the comport number
@xw.func
@xw.sub
def ComPortSelect(strP):
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    comPort = str(strP)
    comPort = 'COM'+comPort
    adapter = pygatt.BGAPIBackend(serial_port=str(comPort))
    adapter.start()
    listOfDevices = adapter.scan()
    wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').value = adapter  **<----- Gives error**
```

[image: Saving object in excell cell error]

```
#Function to use the *adapter* and execute other Pygatt functions
@xw.func
@xw.sub
def ConnectToSelectedDevice(device):
    adapter =  wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').value  **<--**
    deviceHandle = adapter.connect(device)
    .
    .
    .
```

How can i store the required object and use it in other UDF?
Is there any other correct way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used global variable and shared it among the Python UDFs.

I moved ahead with this solution.